# How can I add an HTML tag to specific words in a string and print them along with the rest of the words in PHP?

Tags: php

I've the following string, where I want to add an HTML link to specific words and print them along with the rest of the words;

Input

```
$string = "Every #time it #rains there is #flood";
```

Output

```
$result = "Every <a href='www.abc.com'>#time</a> it <a href='abc.com'>#rains</a> there is <a href='abc.com'>#flood</a>";
```

How do I do it in PHP?

Comment: Have you made any [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and tried anything? It should be pretty straight forward with [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I had some idea as to match the words with regex and use pre_match / preg_replace to add tags, It was all sounding complicated so was looking for other's opinion.

Comment: For the future, when posting a question, you should always include what you've tried. Normally, questions like these are closed for being "unfocused" when they contain no sign of any research effort or any attempt at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first learn how to do it with str_replace.

Here is a more advanced example using pre_replace which you can study after.

```
    $string = "Every #time it #rains there is #flood";

    echo preg_replace("/(#\w+)\s?/", "<a href=\"\${0}\">\${0}</a>", $string);
```

Here is an example with the first word done for you. You can complete the two arrays.

```
    $string = "Every #time it #rains there is #flood";
            
    $find = [
    "#time",
    ];

    $replace = [
    "<a href='abc.com'>#time</a>",
    ];

    $stringreplaced = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);

    echo $stringreplaced;
```

Comment: The first example using `preg_replace()` doesn't at all do what they want though, since it will also set `#time` as the `href`.

Comment: Above example with preg_replace seems to solve my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Siya - If that preg_replace solved your problem, then the expected result in your question was wrong (since it will produce a completely different result). It also seems to be adding an extra space in the end of the tags it matches.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - It solves part of the problem, i.e., it adds html tag to the outcome. Although there is still issue of # in html tag and extra space in the end. Extra space can be solved with change in html. It is the # in the url I am trying to remove. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Anyway using  str_replace in the result solves the # problem too.

Comment: @Siya - In the examples in your question, you have  different URL's in the `href`'s which you can only get by using `str_replace()`. There's no regular expression that can know that `#tag` should be `www.abc.com`.